# How to make Chrome auto select certificate for URLs on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, windows-registry, certificate, selenium

When I run my auto tests on Selenium I receive certificate selection pop up.
[image]

As I managed to find out this issue can be resolved on windows by [creating a registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653785/how-to-stop-chromes-select-a-certificate-window).

Unfortunately that answer did not provide explanation how to do so on Linux. But I found out that there should be some [chrome config file which I can modify in a similar manner](https://superuser.com/questions/295635/linux-equivalent-of-windows-registry#).

Where can I find this file? How is it called and what should I write there in order to resolve the issue? Or maybe there is some other way to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I also just found out ;D

The file you are searching for is a `.json` file, containing the preferred certificate for your URL.

> *Policy file to configure Chrome/Chromium to automatically select a client certificate (useful for Kiosk mode)*

**Filename:** `auto_select_certificate.json`

```json
{
  "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": ["{\"pattern\":\"*\",\"filter\":{}}"]
}
```

Place in the appropriate location:

- `/etc/chromium/policies/managed/`
- `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/`

---

Source: [`auto_select_certificate.json` (GitHub gist)](https://gist.github.com/njh/1d6f2c6acdf39fb3c1b0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you put the info from the gist in your answer directly? Links in answers could become useless if the site hosting it goes down in a few years.